# Proving $G^X$ with $(f_1 \cdot f_2)(x) = f_1(x) \circ f_2(x) $ is abelian

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Hello I don't know if i am doing this correct. I find it difficult to prove the statements. I would like some help.

> $G$ is a group with operation $ \circ$ and $X$ is a non-empty subset. 
> $G^X$ gives the set of all functions $f: X → G$. 
> For $f_1, f_2 \in G^X$ we define $f1 \cdot f_2 \in G^X$ by
> $(f_1 \cdot f_2)(x) = f_1(x) \circ f_2(x) \quad (x \in X)$.

(a). Show $G^X$ is a group with this operation.
To prove $G^X$ is a group we have to prove $G(0)$ (operation on $G$), $G(1)$ (associative), $G(2)$ (neutral element) and $G(3)$ (inverse):

*$G(0)$*: holds as if $f_1, f_2 \in G^X$, then the operation $f_1(x) \circ f_2(x)$ of the function is also in $G^X$

*$G(1)$*: holds. Let $f_1, f_2, f_3 \in G^X$. Then 
$(f_1 \cdot (f_2 \cdot f_3))(x) = f_1 \cdot (f_2 \cdot f_3)(x) = f_1 \cdot (f_2(x) \circ f_3(x)) = (f_1 \cdot (f_2(x) \circ f_3(x))(x) = f_1(x) \circ (f_2(x) \circ f_3(x)) = f_1(x) \circ f_2(x) \circ f_3(x) = (f_1(x) \circ f_2(x)) \circ f_3(x) = ((f_1 \cdot f_2)(x))\circ f_3(x) = ((f_1 \cdot f_2)\cdot f_3)(x)$

*$G(2)$*: If the neutral element is $1 \in G$ we get $(f_1 \cdot 1)(x) = f_1(x) \circ 1 = (1 \cdot f_1)(x) = 1 \circ f_1(x) = f_1(x) \quad \forall f_1 \in G$

*$G(3)$* For $f^{-1}$ we have $f^{-1}(x) = f(x)^{-1}$.
So in the equation we get
$(f_1 \cdot f_1^{-1})(x) = f_1(x) \circ f_1^{-1} = 1$ ?

(b). Prove: $G^X$ is abelian $\iff G$ is abelian.
I don't know. I think we must prove that it is commutative, but I don't know how to continue.

Comment: $\circ$ is not composition here, it is the operation of $G$. Composition of two functions $X\to G$ doesn't make any sense anyway, unless $X=G$. Also, what did you try in the second part? At least one direction should be easy.

Comment: oh yes I see you are right!

Comment: I edited some things

Comment: Note that for the identity you need to clarify the notation. The identity in $G^X$ is the constant function $f(x)=1$, which I believe is what you wanted to write. And again, where are you stuck in the second part? At least the direction that if $G$ is abelian then $G^X$ is abelian is not any more difficult than your proof of associativity.

Comment: But do you think the constant function  $f(x)=1$ is right? Because if it is additive then $ (f_1⋅1)(x)=f_1(x) +1 \neq f_1(x)$ right then it is false? I'm not sure how I should know what the neutral element is

Comment: Any group has an identity element. You decided to call it $1$, doesn't matter what the operation is. You can call it as you wish. Usually the most common notation is $e$.

Comment: [Related.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504246/104041)

Comment: Does my answer answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proving that a abelianness of $G$ implies abelianness of $G^X$ is trivial. For the other direction, since $X$ is non-empty, note that for each pair of elements $a,b \in G$ there exist constant functions $f_1, f_2\in G^X $ mapping the entirety of $X$ to $a,b$ respectively.

Comment: so i don't have to use the definition that $a \circ b = b \circ a$?

Comment: What do you mean? You do have to use it in proving the trivial direction…

Comment: so i can say if $f_1, f_2 \in G$, then $(f_1 \cdot f_2)(x) = f_1(x) \circ f_2(x) = f_2(x) \circ f_1(x) = (f_2 \cdot f_1)(x)$?

Comment: Yes you can. Assuming abelianness of $G$.

Comment: Ok Thanks! And do you think $G2$ and $G3$ are right, or is the neutral element not equal to $1$?

Comment: @Willem Yes it is correct.